# How to call google apps Script Function when Sheet is created?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm looking for a solution to call a function only one time, on Sheet created.
Is there any solution for that?

I was trying to things:

1. adding a call to Function in a cell.
2. Using standard triggers with no lack.

What i'm expecting...?
in cell A1 I want to add a month " " + year and by that other cells know where to look for more informations in different documents.

Comment: If the sheet is created with apps-script, you should be able to modify it when the create sheet function is called...?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. This question doesn't look to be a good fit for this site. If you are able to write code, show what you have tried. Ref. [ask], https://stackoverflow.com/help/ask-wizard.

Comment: @Ping I'm creating the sheet from hand.

Comment: How can I use script called from cell to override another cell?

Comment: than... just make a template with the date pre-input, and copy...as that template sheet instead of creating a blank new one.

Comment: @Ping I'm using a template, but when I'm making a copy, then I want one cell to have a data created by the date when it was created, and it cannot change - and it need to be done by code :)

Comment: Than use script to create the sheet instead… it is like 10 times simpler to do it only with script

Answer (score 0):

Just do it all with script, don't over complicating things.

There is no point to trace for a manually created sheet which has to match the template and not have the date bra bra bra.
Do both 'Create sheet' and 'add Value' in one go is the best solution.

```js
// this function create a costume menu when the spreadsheet open.
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('Costume Menu')
    .addItem('AddSheet','AddSheet') // add a button to the costume menu that call the AddSheet funtion.
    .addToUi();
}

// this function copy the 'template' sheet, re-name it as 'newSheet', and set the value of cell 'A1' to the date of today (the date when this function is called).
function AddSheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const template = ss.getSheetByName('template');
  const today = new Date();
  template.copyTo(ss).setName('newSheet').getRange('A1').setValue(today);
}
```